# can I download entire SPSite or SPWeb to harddisk (ATM i can only download 1 folder)

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, tree, directory

I made a windows form application which maps whole of spsite (given in text box) in form of tree View, but i am wondering if user selects to download whole Site, what code i will be required, i looked into google but find code to download one file or folder which is given below,

Downloading a folder

```
private void bFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            TreeNode currentNode = TreeFolder.SelectedNode;
                SPFolder oFolder = (SPFolder)currentNode.Tag;
                foreach (SPFile file in oFolder.Files)
                {
                    if (CreateDirectoryStructure(tbDirectory.Text, file.Url))
                    {
                        var filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(tbDirectory.Text, file.Url);
                        byte[] binFile = file.OpenBinary();
                        System.IO.FileStream fstream = System.IO.File.Create(filepath);
                        fstream.Write(binFile, 0, binFile.Length);
                        fstream.Close();
                    }
                }
    }

//creating directory        
private bool CreateDirectoryStructure(string baseFolder, string filepath)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(baseFolder)) return false;

            var paths = filepath.Split('/');

            for (var i = 0; i < paths.Length - 1; i++)
            {
            baseFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(baseFolder, paths[i]);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(baseFolder);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Or atleast I can download a scheme (webs with subwebs), Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
SPWebCollection collWebsites = oSiteCollection.AllWebs;
foreach (SPWeb oWebsite in collWebsites)
{


SPFolderCollection collFolders = oWebsite.Folders;

  foreach (SPFolder oFolder in collFolders)
  {

            foreach (SPFile file in oFolder.Files)  
            {
                 // Your code here
            }

  }
```

}